# Accessing Outlook COM addins

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am a novice at programming and it is my first time trying to program a plugin for outlook, which I am having issues with.

When using `Application.COMAddIn("addinname").Update` I get the error that `COMaddin` is not a member for Application. Reading Microsoft documentation seems to state that it is a member of Application.

I'm guessing this is a stupid mistake, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using VB or VBA? In your title it says VB, but tagged is VBA. VBA is solely used in MSOffice, VB (=VB.Net) is used in Visual Studio. Since VBA is not the same as VB, COMAddIn can't work if you use VB, as it is VBA code.

Comment: Hi Kajkrow, thanks for your response. Sorry for the confusion, I am using VBA. Specifically I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and a have created a "Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in" project; which I think is VBA.

Comment: Then you're using VB.NET and not VBA.

Comment: @Kajkrow @Jérémy Gamba
As you can tell I am a complete newbie. How would I go about writing a add-in using VBA. I've already created a simple Macro to enable an Add-in.

`If Application.COMAddIns("crmaddin.Addin").Connect = False Then

Application.COMAddIns("crmaddin.Addin").Connect = True`


How would I go about writing this into an add-in using VB.NET? Or is there a way to create a addin using VBA?

Comment: tbh I have no experience in AddIn-Writing. As far as I know you cannot write AddIns in VBA. VBA's only used for macros. Maybe you can go microsoft.office.core.comaddin.

Comment: @Kajkrow Tried that before and got error COMAddin is a interface type and cannot be used as an expression. Thanks for your help anyway mate.

Answer (score 0):

It is `Application.COMAddIns` (plural). But COMAddin object does not expose the Update method.

To see Outlook objects and their methods and properties, use [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - in your particular case, click Application button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select COMAddins property, click Browse. In the COMAddins window, go to the IEnumVariant tab and double click on an addin.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, This tool is really powerful and provides a lot of information, thanks for that. Unfortunately I still cant work out how to call an addin and enable it through VB.net.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create an add-in that appears in the ribbon as a button, when this button is clicked it disables or enables an already loaded addin, which will be specified in the code. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: To disable an addin, set COMAddin.Connect property to false. You can only disable and enable addins installed in HKCU, but not in HKLM. Why exactly do you want to disable another addin?